# Bootstrap3: How to use two off-canvas sidebars?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this template that initially shows:
Sidebar1 - Content - Sidebar2

But when the user is in mobile view, I need to disappear the two sidebars and that this can be opened by a button, one at a time...

Button1 - opens sidebar1 to the right. 
Button2 - opens sidebar2 to the left.

Anyone know if this is possible or has it done?

Code

```
        <div class="container">

        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                </div>
            </div><!--/span-->


            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <p class="pull-left visible-xs">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas1">
                        Filters <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                    </button>
                </p>

                <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                        Details</button>
                </p>

                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                    <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
                </div>

            </div><!--/span-->

            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
                </div>
            </div><!--/span-->
        </div><!--/row-->


    </div>
```

Javascript

```
    $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function () {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
});

    $('[data-toggle=offcanvas1]').click(function () {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: With the CSS that Bootstrap gives you, you can switch what side the sidebar is on simply by changing `<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">` to `<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">`.

Comment: I already know that. Thanks.

Comment: Shoot a look at mum answer to see if it was helpful, if not, let's see if we can adjust something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed like this:

HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
<div class="row-fluid row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

    <div id="filters"></div>

    <div id="content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="visible-xs"><a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".sidebar-nav"></span> </a></li>
                    <li class="visible-xs"><a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" data-toggle="offcanvas1" data-target=".sidebar-nav"></span> </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="detail"></div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas-left').toggleClass('active');
});

    $('[data-toggle=offcanvasa]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas-right').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Nice, show a JSFiddle for people who are looking at this in the future

Answer (score 0):

Let's give this a try... I added a new row at the bottom of your current HTML to represent the same exact links that are displayed on the edges but are hidden until a button is toggled. Let's take a look at the HTML first:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3  sidebar-offcanvas hide trial2" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="list-group"> <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas pull-right hide trial " id="sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="list-group"> <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>

            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, I copy and pasted the exact same HTML and added the following classes: `hide`, `trial`, `trial2`

**Class hide**: This is a built in BootStrap class that hides all content within the specified tag. I toggle this class with jQuery later on.

**Class trial/trial2** : This is just a random name I chose to make sure the toggle effect was going to work, you can virtually name it whatever you want, but just make sure you reference the tag.

Let's look at the new jQuery:

**jQuery**

```
$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function () {
    $('.trial2').toggleClass('hide');
});

$('[data-toggle=offcanvas1]').click(function () {
    $('.trial').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

It's virtually the same code you had but I have it now toggling the hidden content.

### Conclusion:

I added a few other things as well - such as the ability to hide the two side-navigation bars as the screen shrinks to a smaller size. Just take a look at the code I will provide via a JSFiddle and you will understand it a bit better.

### **[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/597YC/2/)**

Comment: Hi, this is not working for me.. I need to pull left-> Sidebar1.. and <-pull right Sidebar2 and in your demo it shown below Jumbotron. Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: You want it in the jumbotron?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I found how to fix it!